# ISP is DNS Hijacking. Updated DNS to Google OpenDNS, but still hijacked

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, hacking, isp, google-public-dns

I'm visiting India, and saw that their main provider, Airtel, limits the entirety of the internet to just a small handful of websites festooned with their own advertisements, and annoying redirects.

I'm trying to come up with a simple and easy way for the Indian people to have access to freedom of speech and information.

Thus so far, I've updated the DNS records to Google's Public DNS, which allows me to ping, dnslookup, and curl websites such as "askubuntu.com" which are otherwise blocked by Airtel in India.

But if I were to go to them via a browser ( all plugins uninstalled, and with freshly reinstalled browsers ), I am still blocked from accessing the majority of the internet.

Would anyone know what I could do at this point to circumvent a DNS' hacking attempts? A VPN works fine, but I thought it would be more practical to be able to wire something independent of a 3rd party.

I'm using Windows, but am also interested in a Unix solution.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

As your testing proves the ISP is messing not only with DNS but http/(probably) https as well, in this case I don't see any way to circumvent it except to encrypt all the traffic, i.e either VPN/SSH tunneling or Tor browser with Google/OpenDNS for resolving. For the end user Tor would be the easiest, as there are Firefox/Chrome Tor plugins.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution for end-users could be to use Opera's built-in VPN. After all, these days Opera is very close to just being Chrome with another name.

Tor is another way to go of course.